# When using Mockito verify failing on empty row

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit, mockito

Tried to test my client with this following test:

```
private static final HttpPost EXPECTED_POST = new HttpPost(someURI);

    @Test
    public void sendingPostRequest() throws IOException {
        classUnderTest.takeParamsAndSend(REQUEST_STRING);
        verify(client).execute(EXPECTED_POST);
        verifyNoMoreInteractions(client);
    }
```

And in the production code it's something like this:

```
URI uri = createURI();
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(uri);
return client.execute(post);
```

The result is a "Comparison Failure" on the same execute and on the actual, there is an empty row.
Looks something like this:
expected:

```
"client.execute(
    POST somePostRequest HTTP/1.1
);"
```

actual:

```
"client.execute(
   POST somePostRequest HTTP/1.1
);
"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

edit: as stated in comments, most Apache HTTP client API classes does not override `java.lang.Object#equals`, hence you cannot *reliably* use `org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers#eq(T)`.
You will want to use `org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers#argThat` matcher, defining your equality condition in the predicate.

Here is how I tested it:

```java
import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.argThat;

//...
@Test
  void stackOverflow64222693() {

    // Given
    HttpClient client = mock(HttpClient.class);
    URI        uri    = URI.create("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64222693");
    HttpPost   post   = new HttpPost(uri);

    // When
    client.execute(post);

    // Then
    URI      expectedUri  = URI.create("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64222693");
    HttpPost expectedPost = new HttpPost(expectedUri);

    verify(client).execute(argThat(argument -> argument.getURI().equals(expectedPost.getURI()) &&
                                               argument.getMethod().equals(expectedPost.getMethod()) &&
                                               Arrays.equals(argument.getAllHeaders(), expectedPost.getAllHeaders()) &&
                                               argument.getProtocolVersion().equals(expectedPost.getProtocolVersion())));
  }
```

Comment: Tried it now, still failed on the empty row

Comment: Would you mind giving the full qualified name of the `HttpPost` object?
It might be due to a poorly implemented `Object.equals` method.

Comment: Do you mean org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost?

Comment: That explains the issue.
Most objects in Apache HTTP client does not override default `java.lang.Object#equals` method, hence leads to impossible usage of `org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers#eq(T)`.
You will want to use `org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers#argThat`, unfortunately.
Editing my answer to suggest you the solution.